# Can I improve the speed of random access in a bounded-length deque (circular buffer) in Python?

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm working on writing a small log scraping program in Python, which processes a rolling logfile and stores the offsets in the file for lines of interest.

My original solution was running rather quickly on large files but I didn't have a method for clearing the storage which means that if the program were to continue running, the memory usage would steadily increase until the program consumed all of the memory available to it. My solution was to use `collections.deque` with `maxlen` set so that the list would operate as a circular buffer, discarding the oldest loglines as more came in.

While this fixes the memory issue, I'm faced with a major performance loss in calling items from the deque by index. As an example, this code runs much slower than the old equivalent, where self.loglines was not a deque. Is there a way to improve it's speed, or make a circular buffer where random-access is a constant time operation (instead of, I assume, O(n))?

```
    def get_logline(self, lineno):
            """Gets the logline at the given line number.

            Arguments:
            lineno - The index of the logline to retrieve

            Returns: A string containing the logline at the given line number
            """

            start = self.loglines[lineno].start
            end = self.loglines[lineno+1].start
            size = end - start
            if self._logfile.closed:
                    self._logfile = open(self.logpath, "r")
            self._logfile.seek(start)
            logline = self._logfile.read(size)
            return logline
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with all double-linked lists, random access in a `collections.deque` is O(n). Consider using a list of bounded lists so that clearing of old entries (`del outer[0]`) can still proceed in a timely manner even with hundreds of thousands of entries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I assumed that random access in this case would be O(n), given the slowdown--I was wondering if there was any way to implement a circular buffer where random access is O(1) instead of O(n).

Comment: If your inner lists are bounded to 1000 entries then accessing entries at random will be approximately O(1), but clearing old entries will be fast if you remove 1000 at a time.

Comment: Using an inner bounded list and an outer unbounded list would be amortized O(1), but I don't see the point to the inner lists being bounded deques. If each time I reach 1000 entries I need to move to a new list and _not delete_ anything from the old inner list (as would be the case here), the inner lists mind as well be arrays for O(1) lookup benefits. Either way, I need to track the length of each of the arrays and manually purge the outer list, so overall this seems needlessly complicated over just using and clearing one large array.

Comment: I never said that the inner lists should be bounded deques. Bounded, yes. Deques, no.

Comment: Is the speed difference between having a list of 1000 element arrays and deleting the first array and having a large list and deleting the first 1000 elements using a slice (i.e. `mylist = mylist[1000:]` ) significant enough to justify the complications the nesting introduces into the code? I would imagine the slice is sufficiently fast (slower, of course, but still sufficient).

Comment: Deleting the first 1000 elements with a slice would be `del mylist[:999]`, but even that would be (ever slow slightly) faster than creating a new list with the rest of the elements. And deleting a single element would be much faster than even that. As for the "complications", all you'd need to do is check if the last list is full and add the new item in a new list; all the logic could even be put in a class so you wouldn't have to worry about it.